# "Standard" PDE from paper

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading a paper which states that the following PDE can be integrated easily in terms of elementary functions

$$z'^2=\frac{z^2}{1-v^2-z^2}$$

Here $z=z(\sigma-v \tau)$, $z'=\partial z/\partial\sigma$ where $v$ is constant and $\sigma$, $\tau$ $\in (-\infty,+\infty)$.

However, I have never seen such an integral and I do not understand the output obtained from Mathematica.

Is there a standard solution to this, possibly involving elliptic functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an ODE in this form. Set $y(\sigma)=z(\sigma-v \tau)$ and we have
$$ y'^2 = \frac{y^2}{1-v^2+y^2}. $$
Then
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1-v^2-y^2}}{y}y' = 1. $$
Putting $y=\sqrt{1-v^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}$, this simplifies to
$$ \sqrt{1-v^2}\frac{u^2}{u^2-1} u' = 1, $$
which is elementary, the sum of a $1$ and an $\arg\tanh$.